# unable to create 2 tables with same mapping in hibernate due to possible table name collision

Tags: sql, hibernate, annotations

I am new to hibernate and how annotations can create tables in database. 
I think what is wanted is related with : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215471/how-to-map-2-identical-tables-same-properties-to-1-entity), but I am not sure

Suppose there is a class Ticket like this :

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {

    @ManyToMany 
    private Set<Person> buyers;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Person> collectors;

         ...
         ...

}
```

The below line creates a table ticket_person as wanted:

```
private Set<Person> buyers;
```

But the next line, again the class Person is used in object collectors, so table ticket_person can't be created again, but there is a need to have both objects buyers and collectors. So how to get round the problem ? Is there any way in which the default table name ticket_person can be overridden ? Or any other solution that lets create 2 tables with same fields but for different objects in the entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is work for [Jointable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) annotation. As can be seen from the API documentation, all the attributes are optional. In this case only name of the join table should be affected, so following is enough:

```
@JoinTable(name= "ticket_to_collectors")
@ManyToMany
private List<Person> collectors;
```