# How to map one class with multiple tables in Hibernate/javax.persistance?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to use one class to map three tables. I know javax.persistance provides the `@SecondaryTable` annotation to map two tables to one class.

Below is the code, where I have used `@SecondaryTable`. It allows me to define only one secondary table. But I need 3 tables to be used by the same class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
@SecondaryTable(name="table2")
public class TableConfig
    implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "mac", table= "table1")
    private String uniqueIdentifier;
```

Comment: I think here you can find your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215471/how-to-map-2-identical-tables-same-properties-to-1-entity

Comment: If the tables don't have the same structure and don't share same PKs, see this article : https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-map-an-entity-to-multiple-tables/

Answer (score 28):

> I want to use one class to map three tables, From what I know is that javax.persistance provides @SecondaryTable annotation to map two tables to one class

use [@SecondaryTables](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTables.html) to map more than one table.

You can map a single entity bean to several tables using the `@SecondaryTables` class level annotations. To express that a column is in a particular table, use the table parameter of `@Column` or `@JoinColumn`.

---

for example there is 3 entity's namely: `Name` , `Address` & `Student`:

`Name` entity will look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="name")
public class Name implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    public Name(){}

    public Name(int id,String name){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }
        //getters and setters
}
```

`Address` entity will look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="address")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    public Address(){}

    public Address(int id, String address) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.address = address;
    }
        //getters and setters
}
```

`Student` entity will look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
@SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name="name", pkJoinColumns={
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="student_id") }),
    @SecondaryTable(name="address", pkJoinColumns={
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="student_id") })
})
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="student_id")
    private int studentId;

    @Column(table="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(table="address")
    private String address;

    public Student(){}

    public Student(int studentId){
        this.studentId=studentId;
    }
        //getters and setters
}
```

Store like:

```
    Student s= new Student(1);
    session.save(s);

    Name n=new Name(s.getStudentId(),"Bilal Hasan");
    session.save(n);    

    Address address = new Address(s.getStudentId(), "India");
    session.save(address);

    Student ob = (Student)session.get(Student.class, s.getStudentId());

    System.out.println(ob.getStudentId());
    System.out.println(ob.getName());
    System.out.println(ob.getAddress());
```

ouput:

```
1
Bilal Hasan
India
```

Comment: Hi Rembo, Thanks for answering but in this example you are joining three tables into one. In my case I want to just map it. Like three tables are almost identical in DB, and I want only one class to represent them.

Comment: @BilalHasan i think that's not possible, research on it when you find a solution let me know.

Answer (score 12):

you can define one class like below :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")
@SecondaryTables({
      @SecondaryTable(name="table2", pkColumnJoins={@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")}),
      @SecondaryTable(name="table3", pkColumnJoins={@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")})
  })
public class TestEntity {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private int id;

      private String field1;

      @Column(name="column2", table="table2")
      private String field2;

      @Column(name="column3", table="table3")
      private String field3;

      getter and setter...
}
```

In your DB, should has three table, and all of them should has the same primary key "id".

then, use can test like this:

```
TestEntity test = new TestEntity();
test.setField1("field1");
test.setField2("field2");
test.setField3("field3");

em.merge(test);
```

after test, in your DB, you will find one record in each table:

table1:

```
 1, field1
```

table2:

```
 1, field2
```

table3:

```
 1, field3
```

all of them will share the primary key value. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate mapping file you can specify the entity-name mapping with virtual name along with `polymorphism="explicit"` and class name would be physical class name. Like that you may do multiple mappings. While loading the object use entityname (virtual name).