# use JPA entity mapping while storing the entity but ignore fields or a particular table while reading back

Tags: jpa, entity

I am using similar code to what is listed in: [How to map one class with multiple tables in Hibernate/javax.persistance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668350/how-to-map-one-class-with-multiple-tables-in-hibernate-javax-persistance)

I was trying to write a sample login program, based on above example I map my user class to secondary table where I store password field. now when I retrieve back user entity. I also get secondary table field so password is also available in user object.

Is it possible, that during registration I want to use secondary table storage method but when I read back. it should not return password back with user?

How can I achieve this? I am looking for some JPA way like @transient ignore the particular column.

Comment: you are always in control of what is returned from a query, via entity graphs

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go for such implementation.

Best practice is to **never** store a clear-text password, but a digest instead:

```
@Entity
public class Account
{
    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column(length = 32)
    private String password;

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = DigestUtils.md5Hex(password);
    }
}
```

---

It's an uncommon requirement, and JPA patterns will do their best to fight against you :)

But... some way may still be possible:

1. using `Entity Listeners`:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Account
   {
       @Column
       private String username;

       @Column
       private String password;

       @PostLoad
       public void postLoad()
       {
           password = null;
       }
   }
   ```

   be careful: when loaded inside a transaction, a null password may be eventually flushed on commit.
2. removing getter for password:
   if you put annotations only on fields, you can remove `getPassword()` method. Even if the field is populated on load, it's not accessible by external java code.
3. using a `@Transient` combination:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Account
   {
       @Column
       private String username;

       @Column
       private String password;

       @Transient
       private String password2;

       public String getPassword()
       {
           return password2;
       }

       public void setPassword(String password)
       {
           this.password = password;
           this.password2 = password;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thankyou for answer, I am encrypting password in my dao layer. 
I want to do something where I read enttity and associated password field should be null. I am getting encrypted password curreently. I have choice I can manually make it null but is there any mechanism by which we can stop reading the field at JPA layer itself.
Could be a stupid question, but just asking?

Comment: Thankyou dear, I didnot tried it but I think it makes sense. HNY to you.