# Hibernate entity from multiple schemas

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am looking for a way to create an hibernate entity,
which will be built by data from several schemas.
Most of the properties are on a single table on the first schema. One property represents an ID of a row, which is on a table on the second schema.

Is it possible to do such thing?

Comment: You basicly asked a YES/NO question, this is too broad to be answer like this.

Answer (score 1):

This will be possible.

You will need to make sure the second schema GRANTs access to the first one for the relevant table and then you will be able to use the @SecondaryTables annotation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668350/how-to-map-one-class-with-multiple-tables-in-hibernate-javax-persistance) as if it were in the first schema.