# How to tell hibernate which method will be called? i have one class , 2 tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have one class and 2 tables.
1. Items.
The first table is for storing and display the items to the user and from this table the user choose item.(I want to read the items from a file).

2.oredered_items :
Here i want to save the items the user chose.

The tables has the same columns and data types.

```
public class Item {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer price;
}
```

XML mapping :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="entities.Item" table="______________">

    <id name= "id" column="item_id" type="integer">

    </id>
    <property name="name" column="item_name" type="string"/>
    <property name="price" column="item_price" type="integer"/>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This method for reading from a file and insert to the database.

```
public void insertItems()
    {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
        Item currentItem;
        String str;
        String dataString[];
        try {
            File fileForReading = new File(PATH_FILE);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileForReading);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while((str = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                dataString = str.split(" ");
                Integer id = Integer.parseInt(dataString[INDEX_ID]);
                String name = dataString[INDEX_NAME];
                Integer price = Integer.parseInt(dataString[INDEX_PRICE]);
                currentItem = new Item(id,name,price);
                session.persist(currentItem);

            }
            tr.commit();
            session.close();
```

This method read from the table Items and display to the user.

```
public void displayItems()
```

How can i do it?

I want to use the table items only for insert from a file and to display to the user the items , and when he choose what he wants it will store the item in the second table.

Can i tell hibernate : "This method will map to this table , and this method will map to this table" ?

Maybe to create 2 classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this link to map 2 tables to one class
[How to map one class with multiple tables in Hibernate/javax.persistance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668350/how-to-map-one-class-with-multiple-tables-in-hibernate-javax-persistance)

ps : you can also create just a mapping table with two foreign keys to avoid redundant informations about items, and in your class user add a one-to-many join (a user can be related to many items), but your way is more "DDD style"